# Prevent .php files from being redirected with htaccess

Tags: php, node.js, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Because of a node.js instance I have set up the following entry in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:65432/$1 [P]
```

A webserver is up and running which could render PHP files. This is not possible if those are being loaded from the node.js instance.
Now I want to add another rule before the proxy to compute all .php files without looping through the node.js proxy. I have tried it with

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).php ^(.*).php [L]
```

but that doesn't work.
How can this problem be solved?
Thanks

Comment: The second part of your rule (filename) shouldn't have a pattern, it should have a reference to the matched pattern in the first part of the rule.

Answer (score 2):

To use a requested URI unchanged, you must use a [`- (dash)`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

> **- (dash)**
>       A dash indicates that no substitution should be performed (the existing path is passed through untouched). This is used when a flag (see below) needs to be applied without changing the path.

So your rule should look like

```
RewriteRule \.php$ - [L]
```

which means, when a URI ending in `.php` is requested, do nothing and stop further processing.

Answer (score 0):

To exclude .php files from proxy redirect, you can use the following rule

```
RewriteRule ((?!\.php).*)$ http://localhost/$1 [P]
```